# Custom summary formula in report using related user field

Tags: reporting, formula

I'd like to use a custom summary formula in an opportunity report that references a user in a user lookup field on the opportunity, but not the opportunity owner themselves. Is this possible?

Currently when I create the formula, I'm able to access the opportunity owner fields and pull in the field I want, but I want to access a different user who is inside a user lookup field on the opportunity.

Any guidance is appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: I think you will need a Custom Report Type (base object = Opportunity) that exposes the User fields for your custom lookup field.

Comment: @cropredy I tried that and didn't see User as a related object I could bring in for the report type. Am I missing something?

Comment: Choose Custom Report Type with base object = Opportunity, then Edit Layout - then add fields via Lookup (in right hand side of screen)

Comment: @cropredy that did it -- not sure how I overlooked that initially. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOB reports on Opportunity will not make lookup records other than Account and Owner (User) available.

To get lookup fields for a custom lookup to User,

- create a custom report type on Opportunity
- click edit layout
- add  via lookup fields ( right hand side of edit layout screen)